# HighCharts Multi Color

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to implement Highcharts into my projects and want to include color coded Points based on Value. If its below 40 it should be red. 40-70 it should be amber and above that it should be Green

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to provide additional marker element with appropriate fillColor to each of your data points. Documentation is available [here](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#point--color).

Here is an example:

```
data:[{ marker: { fillColor:'#FF0000' }, y:17}]
```